# Change value of DOM.innerText by referencing it through a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

Noob-101:

Throughout my code I want to access and change 'getElementById('#ID').innerText' more easily by referencing it through a variable.

```
let variable = 'getElementById('#ID').innerText;'
```

Now I increment: 'variable ++;'

Problem:
The increment is not showing up in the DOM as if the variable is not referencing the document-property.

I want to avoid to do this every time in my code:

`document.getElementById('#ID').innerText = variable;`

**How can I achieve my goal?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

refer to DOM not the property

```
var v1 = document.getElementById('#ID');
```

Then your code reduced in size

```
v1.innerText = "" + parseInt(v1.innertText) + 1
```

In case the tag is empty, set it zero first or one first, like below

```
if(v1.innerText == "") v1.innerText = "0"
```

Comment: It seems that I can not increment 'v1.innerText'.

Comment: yes you can if it is a number, I will update the answer now, check the answer now

Comment: if the tag empty then parseInt will misbehave so you must have a empty string check

Comment: it is not working.
'v1.innerText' is empty when I print it out.

Comment: does is has any previous text ? come to chat I will help you